# Make IntelliJ key mappings take precedence over IdeaVim

Tags: intellij-idea, phpstorm, ideavim

Ctrl-E in IntelliJ opens Recent Files Dialog.
Ctrl-E in IdeaVim (and in vim) scrolls window downwards.

How to make Ctl-E to open Recent Files Dialog when IdeaVim plugin is active?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can open **IntelliJ Setting** and select **Vim Emulation**.

In there, you can choose conflict shortcuts used by ***IDE*** or ***Vim***.

[image]